# La - pronounces as a soft Ля or hard Ла?

Tags: prononciation

I have been hearing many times the pronunciation of La and some other sounds and don't understand yet, is it soft or solid? I don't know how to represent better this sound in English but if you in Ukrainian or Russian it sounds excellent - soft "ля" and solid "ла", you can check it via google translator. So, how does "La", not " L'.. " or "Le", exactly "La" should sound?

Comment: The categories don't correspond exactly, but I believe it's closer to what you would call a "solid" (or "hard") L. Like in English, the exact articulation can certainly change depending on surrounding sounds. Compare *lame*, *le*, *lion*.

Comment: "ля" and "ла" have somewhat different vowels in Russian, as well as different consonants. Are you sure you're not comparing the vowel of "ля" with *La* rather than, or in addition to, its consonant?

Comment: @PeterShor I was talking about the whole word "ла" and how does it sound. But, seems the question is over, "ла" is the way I should pronounce La, as understood

Comment: Well ... "ла" is certainly much better than "ля", but because of [vowel allophony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology#Allophony) in Russian, neither one of them gives a perfect French pronunciation. The answers just deal with the soft or solid "l" (definitely a solid "l") and not the vowel.

Answer (score 2):

In French every L is pronounced as what you'd call a solid L.

The google translation vocalization is pretty accurate for the French *la*.

Note that as a French I've heard many times foreigners mispronounce words, but never *la*.

Comment: "La Fontaine" should be pronounced as "Ля Фонтэн" or "Ла Фонтэн" (just listen it via g translator)?

Comment: 2nd one. As I said, solid L.

Answer (score 2):

According to the page [Comment prononcer les consonnes russes](http://masterrussian.com/fr/aa081201a_fr.htm), the soft L can be heard in French.

***Lèvre*** IPA [**lɛvʁ**] is reported to have a hard L and ***liège*** IPA [**ljɛʒ**] a soft L. Effectively, the position of the tongue during the L part is different when we pronounce these words.

The /j/ seems to affect the way the previous L is pronounced, which becomes slightly palatalized (in French, *mouillé*).

As there is no /j/ in *La Fontaine*, the /a/ in *la* then keeps the L hard.

However, *Ла Фонтэн* is unlikely to perfectly represent the right pronunciation given the fact there are no nasal vowels in Russian (here *on* is [ɔ̃]), but I guess for Russian ears, identifying this sound is as challenging as for ours dealing with soft and hard consonants.

When I ask GT to say in French "La Fontaine", the L is quite unnatural but more or less acceptable.

When I ask it to pronounce in Russian "ля фонтэн", the L is similar but the *a* is wrong, sound too close to a French *e* like *Le Fontaine*.

When I ask it to pronounce "ла фонтэн", the L is very wrong but the *a* is closer to the French one.

It's getting more interesting when I ask GT to pronounce :

> *[ла ла ла ля ля ля](https://translate.google.fr/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=fr&client=tw-ob#ru/fr/%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D1%8F%20)*

Neither of the sequences are really acceptable, and the wider gap affects the vowels. On the other hand, the French *la la la la la la* is correctly reproducing the standard French pronunciation of the last four "*la*".

So if I trust GT, I'm afraid the Russian phonology isn't able to come near the French *LA* sound.

After switching from Russian to Ukrainian, *[ла ла ла](https://translate.google.fr/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=fr&client=tw-ob#view=home&op=translate&sl=uk&tl=fr&text=%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D1%8F)* sounds closer to the French pronunciation.

Comment: The problem is that, if You play the prononciation of "La Fontaine" in French via g translator it will sound exactly as "ля фонтэн". G translator pronounces it not correctly?

Comment: I'm far to consider them to "exactly" match. See my updated answer.

Comment: Actually there is no difference between *"ла"* or *"ля"* in Ukrainian and Russian(don't know why g translator spells it so). **Ла** sounds 100% same to English **LU**xury. Seems L in English always hard - love, complain etc